# VBA - update sum formula when creating a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have several sheets here

[image: Excel Sheets]

- Total is the calculation of all sheets (exclude Template)
- Template is the master sheet of Nancy, Quincy, Bella, etc

Step on macro :

1. Add new sheet
2. Copy and paste 'Template' sheet
3. Calculate the total on 'Total' sheet (sum formula)

The problem is when I run the second time, the total calculation of last new sheet doesn't include in the calculation.
eg:

1. Run the macro and create a new sheet 'testcopy'
2. Run the macro again
3. Macro create a new sheet 'copy' but the formula doesn't include 'testcopy'

My question : how can I update the sum formula?

Here is the vba code

```
> `'   Start calculation
    Range("L6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Quincy!RC+Nancy!RC+Bella!RC+Abel!RC+Copy!RC"`

?
```

Comment: You might want to accept the answer or delete the question if its not needed anymore

Answer (score 0):

If you use the sum structure in cell `=sum('SheetFirst:SheetLast'Cell!)` it will sum from the first sheet specified till the last sheet specified, and so, will sum every sheet in bewteen. Try to always add  your new sheet after a fixed one (ex. the first one), and put the formula i write in cell like this :

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("First") ' Or whatever will be the first sheet name
Range("A2").Formula = "=sum(First:Last!A1)" ' changing first and last by your first and last sheet names and cell by your cell
```